# How to get custom post types to show up in WP's menu selection?

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I am using the http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/reed-write/ plugin.

It's basically nothing more than a UI to create custom post types in Wordpress. However, I am wondering how I can get any new type to show up in menus I create for Wordpress.

In the menu's tab to the left I can add pages, custom links and even standard 'posts'...but no sign of my custom types.

I would love to kno how to get this to show up. It's not a screen options issue it seems so I'm a little stumped.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this plugin... It does the job for me

wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/